App is ignoring windowSplashScreenBackground after working on themes
I had a very simple splash using API the background was correctly set. I then started working on themes and fixing bugs, and when I was done, the app icon still show a rounded square with correct background, but the splash is either white or black, it is also reacting to night mode, while it was supposed to retain its brand color at all times.
This is my theme.mxl file where I define two themes and the splash
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base Chalkboard Theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Base.Chalkboard" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/chalkboard_backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/chalkboard_textColor</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/chalkboard_tintColor</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>

        <item name="colorAccent1">@color/chalkboard_colorAcent1</item>
        <item name="colorAccent2">@color/chalkboard_colorAcent2</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Base Corporate Theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Base.Corporate" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/corporate_backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/corporate_textColor</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/corporate_tintColor</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/corporate_textColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/corporate_textColor</item>

        <item name="colorAccent1">@color/corporate_colorAcent1</item>
        <item name="colorAccent2">@color/corporate_colorAcent2</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base splash theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/royal_blue</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Base.Chalkboard</item>
    </style>
</resources>

This is how I invoke the splash screen inside my MainActivity this part was not changed:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Handle the splash screen transition.
        long delay = 578L;
        SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> keepSplashOnScreen);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> keepSplashOnScreen = false, delay);

My application theme is Theme.Splash while each activity use the Theme.Base.Chalkboard thne theme is then replaced with Theme.Base.Corporate if the user has selected this theme in the settings.
I tried recreating the mipmap icon, used both SVG and PNG as sources to try something out, I have disabled legacy icons since I target Android 10Q and above devices. I'm running short of ideas about what to test. Commenting out my themes didn't solve the problem. In particular I was worried about the android:background setting.
edit: The background of the splash is #fef7ff so not exactly white.

Theme.Splash has the wrong parent theme. This should rather be:
<style name="Theme.Base.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen" tools:targetApi="s">
    ...
</style>


Is it Theme.Splash parent or also the name that matter? Because it is still white here.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#library

What part? I already do this, I just cannot find what did I broke, it was working before.
